# Allow overflow for numpy types

Tags: python, numpy, overflow

I'm trying to get the "normal" overflow/underflow behavior of C-type languages in Python. To my surprise, a `RuntimeWarning` is raised when I'm trying to get this behavior. Example:

```py
np.uint8(255) + np.uint8(1)
>>> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
```

Is there any way to simulate the desired behavior, i.e., that 255+1 gives 0?

I tried the docs but cannot find this behavior documented.

Answer (score 2):

I believe numpy does give you the correct behavior.

```
In [1]: np.uint8(255) + np.uint8(1)
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
  #!/usr/bin/python2
Out[1]: 0
```

You can suppress the warning by running:

```
In [1]: np.seterr(over='ignore')
Out[1]: {'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}

In [2]: np.uint8(255) + np.uint8(1)
Out[2]: 0
```

Comment: I see. So I guess these uint8 are by no means native? Is there any way to get fast uint8 semantics without resorting to a lower-level language?

Comment: What do you mean by native? I think internally they are indeed represented as a uint8 same as in C, there is just some extra error checking going on.

Comment: It appears that this check is only done for unsigned integers when adding scalars too since it would be too expensive to do for arrays. Have a look here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987.