# Why does numpy.dot give incorrect results?

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

This code:

```
a = np.array([10], dtype=np.int8)
b = np.array([2],  dtype=np.int8)
print(np.dot(a, b))

a = np.array([10], dtype=np.int8)
b = np.array([5],  dtype=np.int8)
print(np.dot(a, b))

a = np.array([10], dtype=np.int8)
b = np.array([20], dtype=np.int8)
print(np.dot(a, b))
```

produces the following output:

```
20
50
-56
```

It appears that `np.dot` will attempt to return the result in the same data type object even if it can't fit. Surely this is a bug? Why doesn't it throw an exception?

Comment: I think it's because np.int8 is not unsigned so you get your result as signed number

Comment: I wouldn't consider overflow a bug. This is typical across many commonly used languages for numerical computing, including C++.

Comment: You are using `np.int8` which has a range of -128 -> 127, 200 is > 127 so it is out of the range of the datatype you are using e.g. try `np.int8(200)`

Comment: I should have been clearer. I understand _why_ it's giving incorrect results, I just don't get why the implementors of `dot` would silently return incorrect results when the value overflows. It feels like this is never the intended behaviour. Why not throw an exception?

Comment: Overflow is a predictable result. More people may not want to throw an exception (are you willing to fail the entire array calculation due to a small amount of data overflow?), and doing overflow check every time will greatly reduce the performance.

Comment: It's not just `dot`.   For all math, `numpy` does not catch overflow of arrays.  Multiplication of individual `np.int8` objects will raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for multiplication and addition.

```
In [89]: np.array([128], 'int8')*2
Out[89]: array([0], dtype=int8)

In [90]: np.array([127], 'int8')*2
Out[90]: array([-2], dtype=int8)        # same int8 dtype
```

But if I work with an element of the array, a `np.int8` object, the result is promoted.

```
In [91]: np.array([127], 'int8')[0]*2
Out[91]: 254    
In [92]: type(_)
Out[92]: numpy.int32
```

I think, though can't offhand produce, there are cases where this kind of thing raises an error.

This has been discussed in other SO, for multiplication, if not for `np.dot`.

This is a overflow question for 'uint8' dtypes, and github issues link:

[Allow overflow for numpy types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910321/allow-overflow-for-numpy-types)

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987 "BUG: Integer overflow warning applies to scalars but not arrays"

Answer (score 1):

It can depends on the `dtype` used. In fact, if I change the dtype:

```
a = np.array([10])
b = np.array([2])
print(np.dot(a, b))

a = np.array([10])
b = np.array([5])
print(np.dot(a, b))

a = np.array([10])
b = np.array([20])
print(np.dot(a, b))
```

The Output is:

```
20
50
200
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because type `numpy.int8` supports integer numbers in the interval `[-128, 128)`, since with just `8` bit you can encode only `256` different numbers. In order to better understand the behavior of casting an integer `n` not in this range in a `numpy.int8`, let's define `n = np.arange(-2**8, 2**8)` and let's see how this array is converted in `numpy.int8`:

```
plt.plot(n, np.int8(n))
plt.xticks([0,  32,  64, 128, 256, -32,  -64, -128, -256])
plt.yticks([0,  32,  64, 128, -32,  -64, -128])
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel("int8(n)")

plt.show()
```

[image: plot result]

As you can see, the conversion function is a periodic function of period `256`; out of range `[-128, 128)` you'll have `n!=numpy.int8(n)`; in general you can say `numpy.int8(n) == ((n-128)%256)-128)`, indeed `((200-128)%256)-128 == -56`

PS. If you only need positive integers you can use the type `numpy.uint8` to encode numbers in the interval `[0,256)`